# A Simple Ruby Script Freezes My Machine

Tags: ruby, freeze

```
CONSTANT = 1000000000000000000
array = (1..CONSTANT).to_a

start = Time.now
array.each do |i|
  if 1000 < i < CONSTANT * 9 / 10

  elsif i > CONSTANT * 9 / 10

  else

  end 
end
finish = Time.now

puts "Running time: #{finish - start} seconds"
```

I wrote the above script in an attempt to figure out how much time saving could be achieved by re-ordering the control branches. The script froze my machine immediately after being run, which couldn't be terminated via CTL + C.
Could someone please point out what happened there?

Comment: Shouldn't this problem be rather addressed to the OS?

Comment: You should set ulimit -v, or your OS's equivalent. Then you'll get a `NoMemoryError` exception in `to_a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a huge array which you don't even need.  That is forcing your machine to start paging (it would take up 5% of the 64-bit address space and your machine certainly doesn't have that much RAM).  Your code is not making it to the loop (the condition in the if statement isn't valid ruby).

```
CONSTANT = 1000 
# start with something small, then increase by 10 
# 10000000 works for me.

start = Time.now
CONSTANT.times do |i|
  if 1000 < i && CONSTANT * 9 / 10

  elsif i > CONSTANT * 9 / 10

  else

  end 
end
finish = Time.now

puts "Running time: #{finish - start} seconds"
```

Comment: More likely it's running out of free memory creating an array of one quintillion integers.

Answer (score 6):

You're iterating over a [huge number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000000000000000000).

Lets say your CPU can iterate one array item per nanosecond (which is good!), that means it'll take `1e9` seconds to iterate over the array. That's 31 years!

Your constant is far, far too large.

Comment: It's unlikely it's even getting to the iteration.

Comment: True, but I find it easier to think about how a CPU would falter over array iteration than array creation.

Comment: Well, okay, but that doesn't change that it's a memory allocation problem and that the iteration in the code shown isn't happening.

Comment: Quite right! But that array, as you say, doesn't need creation; we could just use `for` loop. But if we got rid of the array, we'd *still have* the 'large iteration' problem, so it seems more intuitive to me to consider that as the main problem in the code.

Comment: You could break out of the loop (or at least not lock up the machine and kill it from elsewhere). That aside, whether or not it's "intuitive", the reason he's locking up is because of memory, not because of iteration. What happened? Memory thrashing. Not a long iteration. I guess I tend towards accuracy over intuition.

Comment: This might not be the cause of my problem, but it's a really good point in terms of debugging perspective. Thanks Alex!

Answer (score 3):

What happened is that you tried to create a rather large array:

```
CONSTANT = 1000000000000000000
array = (1..CONSTANT).to_a
```

And your machine got upset with you. You might have better luck using the Range on its own without the `to_a` call.